# Custom method in model - undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model

I have a `rooms` model that looks like follows:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :host
  has_many :bookings

  def space
    if self.bookings.empty?
      return self.capacity
    else
      return (self.capacity - total_booked)
    end
  end

  def total_booked
    total_booked = 0
    room.bookings.each { |booking| total_booked += booking.number_of_guests if
      ((booking.start_date >= @start_date && booking.start_date <= @end_date) ||
        (booking.end_date >= @start_date && booking.end_date <= @end_date)) }

    return total_booked
  end
end
```

In my view I'm trying to call on these methods like so:

```
<% host.rooms.each do |room| %>
  <!-- display information on free rooms -->
  <% if room.bookings.empty? %>
    <p>room #<%= room.id %> is available (0 booked, <%= room.capacity %> free out of <%= room.capacity %>)</p>
  <% else %>
    <% if !(room.space == 0) %>
      <p>room #<%= room.id %> is available (<%= room.total_booked %> booked, <%= room.space %> free out of <%= room.capacity %>)</p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately this gives me the error: `undefined local variable or method 'room'` for the following line:

```
<% if !(room.space == 0) %>
```

I think there might be a syntax error somewhere since I've called on model methods from a view file before but I can't spot it. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

full error log:

```
undefined local variable or method `room' for #<Room:0x00000003a714f0>

Extracted source (around line #25):
22 <% if room.bookings.empty? %>
23   <p>room #<%= room.id %> is available (0 booked, <%= room.capacity %> free out of <%= room.capacity %>)</p>
24 <% else %>
25   <% if !(room.space == 0) %>
26     <p>room #<%= room.id %> is available (<%= room.total_booked %> booked, <%= room.space %> free out of <%= room.capacity %>)</p>
27   <% end %>
28 <% end %>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the line? Looks fine to me.

Comment: Can you show full error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def total_booked
    total_booked = 0
    room.bookings.each { |booking| total_booked += booking.number_of_guests if
      ((booking.start_date >= @start_date && booking.start_date <= @end_date) ||
        (booking.end_date >= @start_date && booking.end_date <= @end_date)) }

    return total_booked
  end
```

`room` is not defined in this context. You probably meant `self.bookings` or just `bookings`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you, I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me!